# Unable to yum install in fedora even as root user

Tags: linux, fedora, superuser

Getting the error `Error: This command has to be run under the root user.` when I try to install in Fedora as root user.  Tried in different ways:

```
Sun May 20 20:18:57 kbsbng@tr
$ sudo yum install mod_ssl
Error: This command has to be run under the root user.
Sun May 20 20:19:00 kbsbng@tr
$ sudo bash
Sun May 20 20:19:03 root@tr
$ yum install mod_ssl
Error: This command has to be run under the root user.
Sun May 20 20:19:15 root@tr
$ su -
[root@tr ~]# yum install mod_ssl
Error: This command has to be run under the root user.
```

Is there any security setting that is causing this?  I am trying all of the above commands by remotely `ssh`ing to the machine.

Comment: your root user seems to be corrupted, can you do this? `usermod -g root root` or `usermod -G root root`? If you can, after doing logout and login.

Comment: You're welcome. For future users, I'll post this as an answer too.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Ok, is there a way I can move this question to Super User? Also, in a way, it is related to programming, since I encountered the issue when I am trying to run a server for the code that I have built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root user seems to be corrupted. If user group of `root` is assigned something out of `root` (or defined groups in `visudo`), it'll not perform.

This will solve your problem since you'll be setting user `root` to group `root`.

```
usermod -g root root
usermod -G root root
```

after entering this, logout and login.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.